# Sum up to every 12 months

Tags: r

I posted this question earlier but the suggestions was not very helpful may be because of unclear question. so sorry for cross posting. My data looks like

```
Months  value
 1  0
 2  0
 3  0
 4  0
 5  0
 6  0
 7  0
 8  0
 9  0
 10 0
 11 0
 12 0
 1  0
 2  0
 3  0
 4  20.32
 5  45.212
 6  27.178
 7  0
 8  0
 9  0
 10 0
 11 0
 12 0
```

No i want to add all 12 monthsin one place and get the new value so that my anwser could be 0 for first twelve months and 92.71 for second twelve months. I have a data of 150 years so any code please?
Rosy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isum from cell 1 -12 in a column and repeat the same process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787638/isum-from-cell-1-12-in-a-column-and-repeat-the-same-process)

Comment: @Metrics the other way around. This version of the question is actually good. The previous one was just horrible and should be closed as a dupe of this. Not to mention that there are no answers in the other question.

Comment: @rosyrana next time you can simply edit your previous question in stead of creating a new one, that is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

We could use one of the aggregating functions after creating a grouping variable.  Assuming that the 'Months' column is ordered, create the grouping variable (`cumsum(df1$Months==1)`) and get the `sum`

```
 tapply(df1$value, cumsum(df1$Months==1), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
 #   1     2 
 #0.00 92.71
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, list(SumValue=sum(value, na.rm=TRUE)),
              by=list(Group=cumsum(Months==1))]
 #   Group SumValue
 #1:     1     0.00
 #2:     2    92.71
```

We could also create the grouping variable using `gl`

```
 as.numeric(gl(nrow(df1), 12, nrow(df1)))
 #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data are actually nicely ordered and complete, like you describe in the sample data, you can just convert the "value" column to a matrix and use `rowSums` on it:

```
matrix(mydf$value, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]   [,5]   [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
# [1,]    0    0    0  0.00  0.000  0.000    0    0    0     0     0     0
# [2,]    0    0    0 20.32 45.212 27.178    0    0    0     0     0     0
rowSums(matrix(mydf$value, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE))
# [1]  0.00 92.71
```

Otherwise, more information would be required to make sure that the grouping of years is possible (as is done with @akrun's answer).